# HTML Table not displaying MySQL data correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, html-table

A table is not rendering correctly while I'm trying to retrieve data from a MySQL table. Basically, I use an if statement to see if anything exists (if the user has posted information) and if they have I go to the else condition which displays the data in an HTML table. Here's the code I've started with for the else statement.

```
else{
//BEGIN JOB POSTING
echo "<table border=1 width=200 height=200>";
while($row_job = mysqli_fetch_array($result_job))
{
echo "<tr>".$row_job['subject']."</tr>";
}
mysqli_free_result($result_job);
echo "</table>";
}
```

The reason I put the width and height and border is so you can see where the table is rendering and where the actual information is rendering. The information is being displayed, it's just being displayed side by side with no spaces and not in a `<tr>`. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Data not rendering in table]

The crazy thing is that if you check the source code of this page it looks like this:

```
<table border=1 width=200 height=200><tr>twkjljl</tr><tr>lkjljl</tr></table>
```

But if you inspect the element in Google Chrome, it looks like this:

[image: Inspected Element]

So I tried a couple things are I changed the code to have them display in `<td>` and it renders correctly. Here's that code and screenshot:

```
else{
//BEGIN JOB POSTING
echo "<table border=1 width=200 height=200><tr>";
while($row_job = mysqli_fetch_array($result_job))
{
echo "<td>".$row_job['subject']."</td><br />";
}
mysqli_free_result($result_job);
echo "</tr></table>";
}
```

[image: Data rendering correctly]

While that's fine, I want the data to display in different rows not different columns and can't see where the error in the code is. What in the world is going on?

Comment: I have the strong feeling that it is a very good idea that you start to learn what valid HTML means and how you can validate your own scripts. A good place to start is http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: While your question has been already answered, I strongly suggest you to read documentation on HTML tables. You might learn a thing or two :). At least you should understand the difference between <tr> and <td> and that <td> tag is placed always within <tr> tag, but do really read that documentation :)

Comment: Ah, haha, I can't believe I overlooked that. I'm busy with MySQL and I completely blanked on my HTML. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `<tr>` you need to encapsulate all data in `<td>`.

```
else{
//BEGIN JOB POSTING
echo "<table border=1 width=200 height=200>";
while($row_job = mysqli_fetch_array($result_job))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row_job['subject']."</td></tr>";
}
mysqli_free_result($result_job);
echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need both tr and td to display elements in a table:

```
     else{
         //BEGIN JOB POSTING
         echo "<table border=1 width=200 height=200>";
        while($row_job = mysqli_fetch_array($result_job))
        {
           echo "<tr><td>".$row_job['subject']."</td></tr>";
        }
          mysqli_free_result($result_job);
        echo "</table>";
     }
```

The following is one row of a table.

```
    <tr><td>row1</td></tr>
```

If you want add more columns, you add more two td's.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `<tr><td>` in pair:

```
else{
//BEGIN JOB POSTING
echo "<table border=1 width=200 height=200>";
while($row_job = mysqli_fetch_array($result_job))
{
echo "<tr><td>".$row_job['subject']."</td></tr>";
}
mysqli_free_result($result_job);
echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`TR` is a table row, which consists of many table cells `TD`.

Thus an HTML table looks like:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to make use of PHP 5.4 for [Iterator Support of Mysqli Results](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php):

```
foreach ($result_job as $row)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$row_job[subject]</td></tr>";
}
```

If you can not use that PHP version - I assume you are not doing anything `mysqli_*` specific in the sense that you need exactly that extension - use the `PDO` extension instead. It has that support since much longer.